# Publishing mvc website with sql database in App_Data folder

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I published my mvc4 application to my local IIS and it works fine with my SQL Server Express database in the app_data folder. However, when I publish it to my FTP site on the internet and run it, it errors out. It does not appear to be connecting to database in app_data folder. I know that for it to work on my local IIS, I needed to give it permissions for network service.  Do I need to contact my internet hosting to give permissions to this folder as well or do I need to make changes to web.config connection strings?

**Error:**
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: Gibrun is right to ask about the error - we need to know what it is. It also matters which version of IIS you are using, and if you are using user instances or not - can you tell us this? I have just updated my answer with more info, but there are a lot of options you need to look at based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your application pool account has permissions for SQL Express, you will be ok.

There are a few things you need to consider:

- are you using a user instance; and/or
- is your app pool running on IIS 7 as an application pool identity?

#### User Instances

I am guessing it is trying to attach to a [user instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms143684%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) ([see the ADO.NET reference here as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx)). If you are unsure, see if your connection string contains

```
User Instance=true;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\InstanceDB.mdf
```

There is a great MSDN article on using SQL databases in asp.net called ["Using SQL Server Express with ASP.NET"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it is too long to repeat the whole thing. While it talks about using it in general, the principles apply to deployments as well, and cover user instances.

If it is the case you are using user instances then you also need to check that SQL Server was installed to allow them. You can do this by running [`sp_configure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx) to view the setting:

```
exec sp_configure 'user instances enabled'
```

If it returns "1" then you have user instances enabled, if not then `exec sp_configure 'user instances enabled', '1'` will enable them (and use `'0'` to disable them).

User instances aren't always the best choice, so before doing this, check that you don't want to use a normal instance instead.

#### IIS 7 application pool identities

As IIS 7 onwards introduced [application pool identites](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities). Sometimes you need to give them access to sql server:

- Make sure your application pool is started (this is crucial) (browse to the home page on the site)
- Open up SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)
- Go to Security -> Logins at the server level
- Right click, click create new login
- In the login field, type `IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPoolName` and create the user (set any other settings you need)

  - I don't use the search function here, but the name will verify as long as the app pool is running, so you can if you want.
- Go to your database and add the login as a database principal with the appropriate permissions

  - db_owner is slightly aggressive for production systems, but simplest to get started when creating new tables etc., and then later you can dial that down to data reader, writer etc)

Or, you can run:

```
CREATE LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPoolName] FROM WINDOWS;
USE MyDatabase
GO
CREATE USER MyAppPoolUser FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPoolName];
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'role_name', N'MyAppPoolUser' -- role name could be db_owner
```

Application pool identities are now best practice, and should be used whenever possible (there are scenarios where that isn't feasible, such as multi-server setups).

#### Other errors - application pool identities and user instances

If you see the error *"Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in reading registry keys. The connection will be closed"* then you also have a problem with IIS application pool identities and the user instances. To fix this:

- Go to IIS manager
- Go to advanced settings on the application pool
- under process model, click "Load User Profile"

There is also an iis.net article on these and user instances called ["Application Pool Identities and SQL Server Express"](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities-and-sql-server-express) (Thomas Demi) which is useful.

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: @user1929393. I am sure you have, but its worth checking: have you changed your connection string when you deploy to the ftp site to reflect the name of the sql server on your web server?

Comment: this is my connectionstring:   connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|JokesDB.mdf;User Instance=true"

Comment: @user1929393. So you should check that the name of the sql server on the server is `.\SQLEXPRESS` and not `.`, then check user instances are enabled, then check permissions as detailed in my answer.